# Is there a way to move type definition to a new package for Go in VScode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I have a certain struct in package A, and it has been used in a lot of different places. Now I want to refactor the codebase, and I want to move it into another package B. In Goland, I can do that quite easily, but I haven't been successful find out how to do it in VScode. Is it supported?

I haven't been able to find any description about such action in vscode refactoring documentation.

Comment: any refactoring can be done by hand with copy/paste

Comment: @rioV8 true, thanks for the valuable input.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is supported in [Goland](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/move-refactorings.html), but not in VsCode. There is an open [issue](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues/2721) in vscode-go for it. Also, there is an open issue for [gopls](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/57016) for it too.